# How do you add and use just the Django version 1.2.1 template?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates

Thanks for the help.

Currently I import in gae:
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
then use this to render:
self.response.out.write(template.render('tPage1.htm', templateInfo ))

I believe the template that Google supplied for Django templete is version 0.96.

How do I setup and import the newer version of only the Django template version 1.2.1?

Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until Issue 3230 http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3230 is resolved and Django 1.2 is added as a library, you need to zip up django 1.2.1 and include it with your project.

Is there something specific you want out of 1.2 that isn't in 1.1?  Because you could use 1.1 since it is available as a library already by following this http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django

which is:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.1')
```

Comment: Thanks.
I got 1.1 to work, but would be nice to know when 1.2 will be available. I like to use the {% if somevar == "x" %}

Comment: If you *star* the appengine issue:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3230

Google will notify you via your google account when the status is updated.